# I can't to hightlight Rouge

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rouge

rouge_helper.rb:

```
module RougeHelper
require 'rouge'

  def rouge(text, language)
    formatter = Rouge::Formatters::HTML.new
    lexer = Rouge::Lexer.find(language)
    formatter.format(lexer.lex(text))
  end

end
```

app/assets/stylesheets/rouge.css.erb:

```
 <%= Rouge::Themes::Base16.mode(:light).render(scope: '.highlight') %>
```

index.html.erb:

```
<% @articles. each do |article|%>
<p><%= article.title%></p>
<p><%= raw rouge article.text, 'ruby'%></p>
<% end >
```

view page source:

```
<p>test </p>
<p>&lt;span class=&quot;k&quot;&gt;def&lt;/span&gt; &lt;span class=&quot;nf&quot;&gt;test&lt;/span&gt;
 &lt;span class=&quot;nb&quot;&gt;puts&lt;/span&gt; &lt;span class=&quot;s1&quot;&gt;&#39;Hello&#39;&lt;/span&gt;
&lt;span class=&quot;k&quot;&gt;end&lt;/span&gt;</p>
```

Comment: i don't know what you have in `article.text` but `<%= raw rouge(%(puts "hello"), "ruby") %>` seem to work fine, what do you get? (rouge v4.1.3)

Comment: Not highlight. Display puts 'hello' without  highlighting

Comment: highlighting comes from css `scope: '.highlight'` so: `<pre class="highlight"><%= raw rouge(%(puts "hello"), "ruby") %></pre>`

Comment: I add <pre class="highlight"><%= raw rouge(%(puts "hello"), "ruby") %></pre> in my index.html.erb and it work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I have in my page source <span class="nb">puts</span> <span class="s2">"hello"</span>.Why?

Comment: What method create <pre> tag?

Comment: "What am I doing wrong" - i'd need to see what you have in `article.text`. "Why?" - what do you mean? that's what you supposed to have there.  "<pre> tag?" - you add that tag yourself. it's up to you to wrap the code in pre tag (or whatever works for you) and add `.highlight` class.

Comment: Thanks, it is work. I have one more question. I have another project.  I run it by foreman. It has builds folder and stylesheets folder, there is also Procfile and package.json. After adding rouge.css.erb in stylesheets folder, code formats but not highlight, but <pre class="highlight ruby"> creates in index page. Project just doesn't see <%= Rouge::Themes::Base16.mode(:light).render(scope: '.highlight') %>.

Comment: you have to load the css somewhere: like `//= require rouge` in application.css, or `stylesheet_link_tag "rouge"` in your layout.